# Using AXII when mounted

Tags: the-witcher-3

I noticed you can only use AXII sign when mounted and only on the horse. Why? Does it reduce fear level or something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are mounted on the horse, the AXII sign is used to calm it down (reduce its fear level).

When used in combat and not mounted on the horse, it is used to stun people.

It can also be used in certain conversations to influence a person (be warned: this does not always yield a favourable outcome).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was asking specifically about the effect when mounted. Is the fear reduction instant or does it merely increase the rate of fear state restoration? I tried it last night twice and I didn't notice any obviously perceptible change.

Comment: You use it when the fear bar starts rising. It will decrease it immediately.

Comment: Personally, I've found it pretty useless if you're surrounded anyway, since it begins rising back up almost immediately (unless you have really good blinders and the enemy type isn't one to increase the fear level quickly)

Comment: Using Axii in dialogue always give bonus exp, and at worst gets you in a fight you coouldn't avoid anyway. Unless I missed a specific encounter @5pike was thinking of?

Comment: I tested it tonight and it works as described. I'm also not sure about its usefulness, @DangerZone. It seems I cannot do it on the move. I found it better to run away and circle back -- during which time the fear level drops anyway.

Comment: Regarding the Axii dialog option not always being favorable: rule of thumb is that you shouldn't try it when there are more than two or three people present who might know a thing about magic.